# Add extra row for each group in dataframe - pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a large data frame which I have sampled:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'case': [1,1,1,2,2], 
                   'IssueDatetime': ['2010-01-01 09:00:00', '2010-01-01 09:00:00', '2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 09:00:00'],
                   'endtime':['2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00'],
                   'Regions': ['EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH', 'EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH', 'EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH','NORTHEAST COAST','NORTHEAST COAST'],
                  'forecastTime': ['2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 15:00:00','2010-01-01 19:00:00','2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 12:00:00'],
                   'forecast_Dir':[150,180,45,45,45],
                   'windSpeed':[20,90,35,45,15]})
```

Each case has an endtime associated with it. Using pandas how can I duplicated the last row for every case and make the endtime the forecastTime for that final row? Desired result:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'case': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2], 
                   'IssueDatetime': ['2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 09:00:00', '2010-01-01 09:00:00', '2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 09:00:00'],
                   'endtime':['2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00'],
                   'Regions': ['EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH','EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH', 'EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH', 'EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH','NORTHEAST COAST','NORTHEAST COAST','NORTHEAST COAST'],
                  'forecastTime': ['2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 15:00:00','2010-01-01 19:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00','2010-01-01 09:00:00','2010-01-01 12:00:00','2010-01-03 03:00:00'],
                   'forecast_Dir':[150,180,45,45,45,45,45],
                   'windSpeed':[20,90,35,35,45,15,15]})
```

I need to apply this method for the ~13000 cases I have in my original dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could first create a dataframe keeping only the last row and then concatenate the results

```
added = df.groupby(['case'], as_index=False).last().assign(forecastTime=lambda subdf: subdf.endtime)
pd.concat([df, added]).sort_values(by=['case'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) for last duplicated rows, overwrite column, add to original by [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) and last sorting:

```
df1 = df.drop_duplicates('case', keep='last').assign(forecastTime = lambda x: x['endtime'])
df2 = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index(kind='mergesort').reset_index(drop=True)
print (df2)
   case        IssueDatetime              endtime  \
0     1  2010-01-01 09:00:00  2010-01-03 03:00:00   
1     1  2010-01-01 09:00:00  2010-01-03 03:00:00   
2     1  2010-01-01 09:00:00  2010-01-03 03:00:00   
3     1  2010-01-01 09:00:00  2010-01-03 03:00:00   
4     2  2010-01-01 09:00:00  2010-01-03 03:00:00   
5     2  2010-01-01 09:00:00  2010-01-03 03:00:00   
6     2  2010-01-01 09:00:00  2010-01-03 03:00:00   

                                Regions         forecastTime  forecast_Dir  \
0  EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH  2010-01-01 09:00:00           150   
1  EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH  2010-01-01 15:00:00           180   
2  EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH  2010-01-01 19:00:00            45   
3  EAST COAST-CAPE ST FRANCIS AND SOUTH  2010-01-03 03:00:00            45   
4                       NORTHEAST COAST  2010-01-01 09:00:00            45   
5                       NORTHEAST COAST  2010-01-01 12:00:00            45   
6                       NORTHEAST COAST  2010-01-03 03:00:00            45   

   windSpeed  
0         20  
1         90  
2         35  
3         35  
4         45  
5         15  
6         15
```

Answer (score 1):

An option would be using `.groupby` to select the last line and `.concat` to join them

```
s = df.groupby('case').tail(1)
s.loc[:, 'forecastTime'] = s.loc[:, 'endtime']

df_new = pd.concat([df, s], ignore_index=True).sort_values('case')
```